# using awk to print every second field

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have the following input file and I wish to print every second field:

```
A=1=B=2=C=3
```

To get the following output:

```
1 2 3
```

I have tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="="; OFS=" "} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2); print ($i) }' input_file
```

and it clearly doesn't work. I think I have the for loop portion correct, but something is wrong with my print portion.

Thank you.

Comment: in case you want to learn some `sed`: `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]=\([[:digit:]]\)/\1 /g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS== -v ORS=" " '0==NR%2' input_file
1 2 3
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS==`

  Set the input record separator to `=`.
- `-v ORS=" "`

  Set the output record separator to a space.
- `0==NR%2`

  Print every other line.

  `NR` is the line number.  `NR%2` is the line number modulo 2.  Thus, the condition `0==NR%2` is true on every other line.  When the condition is true, the action is performed.  Since no action is specified, the default action is performed which is to print the record.

#### Alternative

The key issue in the original code was a misplaced semicolon.  Consider:

```
for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2); print ($i)
```

In this case, the `print` command is executed only *after* the `for` loop exits.

Try:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="="; OFS=" "} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)print $i }' input_file
1
2
3
```

Or, if you want the output on one line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="="} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)printf "%s ", $i; print "" }' input_file
1 2 3
```