# AWK: print every second field with different output inline-separator and different output EOF separator?

Tags: awk

This question is related to [using awk to print every second field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208666/using-awk-to-print-every-second-field) but I am having problems to print it neatly

```
$ cat printEachSecondColumnValue 
1,11,111,1111,11111
2,22,222,2222,22222
3,33,333,3333,33333
4,44,444,4444,44444
5,55,555,5555,55555
6,66,666,6666,66666
$ gawk -v RS=, -v ORS="\n" '0==NR%2' printEachSecondColumnValue 
11
1111
22
2222
33
3333
44
4444
55
5555
66
6666
$ gawk -v RS=, -v ORS="," '0==NR%2' printEachSecondColumnValue 
11,1111,22,2222,33,3333,44,4444,55,5555,66,6666,
```

while I want to get

```
11,1111
22,2222
33,3333
44,4444
55,5555
66,6666
```

**Can you explain the behaviour of the command piece-by-piece and how to define the inline-separator and EOF differently to get the two columns?**

Comment: The `RS` being `,` means that the line terminator is **not** a record separator. The `1111<newline>2,` are one record.

Answer (score 2):

> while I want to get
>
> ```
> 11,1111
> 22,2222
> 33,3333
> 44,4444
> 55,5555
> 66,6666
> ```

Pardon this intrusion of the obvious, but that's just

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","} { print $2, $4 }'
```

for the given data.

To print the even fields regardless of how many there are, we can replace the `print` with a loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       FS = OFS = ","
     }                                                    
     {                                                                          
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {                                           
         printf "%s", i                                                         
         if (i + 2 <= NF)                                                       
           printf OFS                                                           
       }                                                                        
       printf "\n"                                                              
     }'
```

Alternative logic for the commas:

```
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {
         if (i > 2)
           printf OFS
         printf "%s", i
       }
```

Now, for something a little different. What if we **edit** the fields to the set we want? Then we can just print them with `print`!

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","}
     {
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {
         j = i/2
         $j = $i
       }    
       NF = j
       print
     }'
```

When we assign to `NF`, it means there are now that many fields.
If we change any of the fields, or change `NF`, then the value of `$0` which `print` prints by default is re-calculated by combining the field values with `OFS` between them.

Smarter Awk, implemented as a Lisp macro in the TXR Language:

```
$ txr -e '(awk (:set fs "," ofs fs)
               (t (set f (select f (range 1 : 2)))
                  (prn)))'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,4,6,8,10
1,2,3,4
2,4
```

Here the `(:set ...)` clause is for setting up initial variables; `fs` is the analog of `FS` and set to the comma; `ofs` is set to `fs`.

The `t` means Boolean true: this clause fires for every record. We then edit the list of fields `f` by selecting the second, third, fourth, which are indicated by the zero-based list `(1 3 5 7 9 ...)`. We generate an infinite, lazy version of this index list using `(range 1 : 2)` and feed it to the `select` function.

Assigning to `f` causes the record variable `rec` (analogous to `$0`) to be re-constituted with `ofs`. The `prn` function with no arguments prints `rec`.

We can get rid of that modification of `f` and side effect of setting `rec` by feeding the output of `select` directly as arguments to `prn` with `apply`:

```
txr -e '(awk (:set fs "," ofs fs)
             (t [apply prn (select f (range 1 : 2))])))'
```

"Apply `prn` to the even fields, with `ofs` being the comma."